# i have added path to C:\MinGW\bin' but it's not recognized when i type gcc "file name"

Tags: c, windows, powershell, mingw

For best explaination pls look at img.
Being new i installed VS Code (added path), installed MinGW minimalist, applied changed by marking everything in installation ,copied the path in environment variable, interestingly i can't open gcc by clicking on it. if i go to Windows powershell and try to run (in admin mode) it gives fatal error but i type ar then it opens.if i type C:\MinGW\bin then it doesn't recognizes it. Upon removing the path of gcc, it doesn't shows fatal error when i type it's path and not recongnizable when i type gcc.Is there a way to fix it? i watch tutorials but they didn't help even tho i followed them step by step.Some of my environment variable were different from the varibale excluding C:MinGW\bin.BTW pls tell ans in ez way because i just installed C as my 1st programming language.

[image: confusion]

Comment: Your screenshot shows that `gcc` already _is_ available via `$env:PATH`, but you're mistakenly calling `C:\MingGw\bin` - i.e. the _directory_ in which `gcc` is located - in lieu of `gcc` in your last attempt.

Comment: On a general note: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: sorry i didn't knew. can you tell what i should do to fix this problem

Comment: `gcc first.c` looks correct in principle, but the error message is telling you that _no such file exists_ (in the current directory).

Comment: Please enhance your prose, it is barely readable. Blanks and capitalization are necessary for comprehensibility, and paragraphs give structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the correct steps:

- add `C:\MinGW\bin` to the `PATH` environment variable
- open a new Powershell or Command Prompt (not an existing one, and don't Run As Administrator) and type `gcc --version`)
- open VSCode and make sure the compiler is configured properly, see also: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

MinGW is old, I recommend using newer MinGW-w64 which is much more up to date and support both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows. You can get a standalone version from https://winlibs.com/